# How remove the 'lightbox' effect at my images on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying remove the effect at my images, but I do know where I have to remove this code:

My website:
http://ebackstage.com.br/comece-o-ano-com-o-pe-direito/

I want remove the effect when click on some image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an installed plugin LightboxBank [Lightboxbank Plugin](https://bg.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-lightbox-bank/). On its page it says

> It allows you to enable it on all WordPress images and attachments as well.

So you must remove this plugin if you want to disable lightbox on all images or view its settings to determine how to enable lightbox only for certain photos.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the lightbox plugin installed.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

yes with out removing plugin you can remove lightbox effect for few images.

click on edit image

and then `LINK to -> NONE`

and then update image.